# JavaFX Filling an area between lines and circles with color

Tags: javafx, automatic-ref-counting, background-color

I have made a group with lines, labels and circles. there are three circles, they have the same center but each has  a different radius. The circles are crossed by lines so there is an area which is surrounded on the top by an arc, left and right by a line and on the bottom with an arc. in the middle of this area is the number 8 as a label.
I can't post a picture yet but i hope u can imagine what I mean.

I have read something about an fillinf algorithm that starts at a specific position and then checks his neighbour-pixel if it is colored or not. If not then it gets colored, if the pixel is black like in my picture it would stop. the problem here is that the two holes in the number 8 would keep white. And i don't know the exact position of the number so I could start this algoithm inside of a hole of the eight.

So my question is: how can i fill an area which is surrounded by two parts of circles and two lines with color.

Comment: Construct a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html) and fill it. Flood fill is a algorithm you could perhaps do on a image/`Canvas`, but not on a JavaFX scene...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. provide few illustration/example to elaborate your problem. Also provide what you have done so far. Also visit this link : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for your comment, I will try that!